# How to run coverage.py on a directory?

Tags: python, coverage.py

I have a directory `tests` that includes a lot of different tests named `test_*`.

I tried to run `coverage run tests` but it doesn't work.

How can I run a single command to coverage multiple files in the directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `--include` to only include files in particular directories. It matches file paths, so it can match a subdirectory.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a complete example with commands from the same PWD for all phases in one place. With a worked up example, I am also including the testing and the report part for before and after coverage is run. I ran the following steps and it worked all fine on osx/mojave.

> 1. Discover and run all tests in the test directory

`$` `python -m unittest discover <directory_name>`

> Or
>   Discover and run all tests in "directory" with tests having file name pattern *_test.py

`$` `python -m unittest discover -s <directory> -p '*_test.py'`

> 2. run coverage for all modules

`$` `coverage run --source=./test -m unittest discover -s <directory>/`

> 3. get the coverage report from the same directory - no need to cd.

`$` `coverage report -m`

> Notice in above examples that the test directory doesn't have to be
>   named "test" and same goes for the test modules.

Answer (score 10):

You can achieve that using `--source`. For example: `coverage run --source=tests/ <run_tests>`

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers here quite worked for me. I found that coverage and pytest worked fine though:

```
coverage run -m pytest
```

This was run at the project folder. It was able to find the folder called tests, and run all the tests (which was split into multiple python files and had a `__init__`.py file) within them. To see the report run:

```
coverage report
```

Comment: `coverage report -m` to also show the missing lines (not covered yet)

Comment: I use `unittest`, so it's funny that your answer `coverage run -m pytest`worked for me, while others or `coverage run -m unittest' don`t