# How to get coverage for multiple test files with coverge.py

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py, test-coverage

Sorry if the questions already been asked, but when using `coverage.py` to get Code Coverage reports, how do I get the coverage throughout mutliple test files? For example, if I had a directory structured like so:

```
package
├── README.md
├── LICENSE
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   └── test_file.py
│   └── test_file2.py
├── package
│   └── __init__.py
│   └── another_file.py
```

How do I get the coverage report for *all* the files in the tests directory with coverage.py?

Comment: Actually, it seems this question has already been asked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44812538/how-to-run-coverage-py-on-a-directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python unit test coverage for multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47497001/python-unit-test-coverage-for-multiple-modules)

Comment: @VirtualScooter I'm not trying to test multiple modules, rather multiple files. I found `--include` but it didn't work when I tried it.

Comment: It sounds like you are running one test file at a time.  Use a test runner that can run all your tests, and use coverage with it.  If that's not what's going on, provide more information, like how you are running your tests.